# when executing macros/vba how can they be applied on merged cells?

Tags: vba, cells

I have the following question: A member from this forum yesterday provided a very good solution to my problem.  I have two similar excel workbooks with more than 100 sheets in each, with the same sheet names. I wanted VBA to copy the data from sheet A in workbook A to sheet B in workbook B.

```
Sub GetDate()

Dim workbookA As Workbook, workbookB As Workbook, sheetA As Worksheet, sheetB As        Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, sheetName As String
Set workbookA = Workbooks("clients.xls")
Set workbookB = Workbooks("KYC.xls")

'Loop through each worksheet in Book A
For Each ws In workbookB.Worksheets
    Set sheetA = workbookA.Worksheets(ws.Name)
    Set sheetB = workbookB.Worksheets(ws.Name)
    sheetA.Range("C5").Copy sheetB.Range("E31")
Next
End Sub
```

I want to use it agan to get another values from another cell and insert it on workbookB on the approprate sheet each time.  The problem is that on workbook A the cell I want to copy is a merged cell and so is the destination cell.  I tried to give a name to each of the merged cells but I can't seem to make it. Can someone help if it can be solved?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sheetA.Range("C5").MergeArea.Copy    ' copies the merged cells that include C5
sheetB.Range("E31").PasteSpecial     ' pastes what was copied into E31 and any merged cells it is part of
```

Comment: I just tried. First it says "there is already data here, do you want to replace it?" There is no data, but anyway I press Yes and then it says "runtime error: you can't do that to amerged cell

Comment: This works fine for me on Excel 2013. Try using .PasteSpecial. Also if you want to ignore the alert put this at the start of your sub "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" - Don't forget to set it back to True

Comment: I am quite ignorant regardng VBA.Do you mean to wrte it like that?    sheetA.Range("C6").MergeArea.Copy sheetB.Range("B8").MergeArea or like that ?                                         sheetA.Range("C6").MergeCells.Copy sheetB.Range("B8").MergeCells.Paste Special

Comment: I noticed that if the destination cells are not merged, then the VBA works.  But since I copy-paste an adress, if they are not merged it appears badly.

Comment: Write it exactly as it appears in the answer - change the range addresses to what you want - don't change the rest of the code.

Comment: I found the problem (sorry for bothering you so much) Merged area 1 and merged area 2 were not the same size.  I made them have the same size, did exactly as you said and it worked.  thank you very much for your help